# Navigation pop animation unexpected - jumps off screen

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, size-classes, uitraitcollection

I'm having an issue where my `UINavigationController`'s default pop animation has unexpected behavior - the popped controller sometimes jumps off-screen left or right.

The issue seems related to overriding the controller's `UITraitCollection`.

I have a universal app, and on iPad, a custom `UIPresentationController` to display a nav in a partial modal, where its width is a fraction of the screen width. Thus, I override the `horizontalSizeClass` to compact on the `UIPresentationController`'s `overrideTraitCollection` property, so all controllers presented in this "half modal" assume their iPhone layout.

Overriding that size class seems to trigger the bug. Suddenly, when popping a controller within that "half modal", the animation is messed up in landscape (it either jumps left or right).

Here's an example of what it looks like:
[image: unexpected-pop-animation]

**Attempts**

First, when I get rid of the `traitCollection` override, the bug goes away. Obviously though, I want to override the horizontal size class, because these views are reused elsewhere in regular environments too.

Thus, I tried overriding the `horizontalSizeClass` of the modal's children in other ways, like:

- Using the modal Nav's `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to override
  each child's `traitCollection` on
  `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` – this seemed to make no difference
- Having the first nav child override the secondary child's `traitCollection`
  before it pushes it

Like so:

```
[self.navigationController setOverrideTraitCollection:compactTraitCollection forChildViewController:secondaryController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondaryController animated:YES];
```

Interestingly, this fixes the pop animation bug, but then my primary controller (`self`) is still in a Regular `horizontalSizeClass`... Furthermore, this seems like bad practice. My view controllers shouldn't need to know anything about their presentation! That should be handled by the `UIPresentationController`, and seems supported by the fact that the presentation controller has a `overrideTraitCollection` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was the implementation of `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, relying on size classes:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // Don't do this if you ever override size classes
    if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Because the `horizontalSizeClass` of the "half modal" controllers was overridden to use `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact`, they were assuming a Portrait-only orientation. The navigation controller didn't know how to handle that.

### The solution:

Changing the above code to rely on device type fixes the issue:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // Basing off of size classes causes unexpected behavior when overriding size classes - use interface idiom instead
    if (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This probably should have been the way to go in the first place, but given Apple's encouragement of being device-agnostic and only relying on size classes, it wasn't what I did.

Anyway, for prosperity, here's the test project I used to debug this: https://github.com/bradgmueller/half-modal-test